# Is there data visualisation tool for postgresql which is capable of displaying inter schema relations as well?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship, postgresql-9.1

Operating system used is linux. I have tried *Navicat* and *SQL Power Architect*. They did display relations between tables in the same schema. I have some foreign key constraints which reference tables in a different schema.

- Am I missing something with respect to Navicat and PostgreSQL Maestro? Can they not display the inter schema relations?
- Is there data visualisation tool for postgresql which is capable of displaying inter schema relations as well?

**UPD**  Sorry for editing your question, but I found it useful. Because this is closed I can not answer (maybe there should be site for that??)

For drawing table relationship of your database you can try [this script](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/GraphViz-DBI/examples/dbigraph.pl) of [GraphViz::DBI](https://metacpan.org/release/GraphViz-DBI) perl module.

As result you will get the [GIF](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/TEEJAY/GraphViz-DBI-0.02/examples/mydb.gif) with relations

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've recently discovered [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). It automatically detects relations between tables in a visual manner. You can move tables around, change colors, see foreign keys, etc. It's extremely good. Fully compatible with PostgreSQL

Querying and manipulating data using the GUI is extremely easy.

Not only that you can use it with all major SQL and noSQL databases, so all your data can be managed in just one place.

Comment: DBeaver is really good for this, thanks.

Comment: it seems this is a feature only available in the enterprise edition

Answer (score 14):

DbVisualiser seems to do what you're after: http://www.dbvis.com/doc/main/doc/ug/databaseSpecific/postgresql.html

There's also a list of alternate tools here (though it's not as query-able a list as you'd expect from a DB):
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: looking.. and currently trying out [_DbSchema_](http://www.dbschema.com) ..

Comment: Although DbViz does what I posted the question for, It still lacks some nice features. Like listing of triggers pertaining to tables etc.. +1 for mentioning it though.

Comment: DbVisualiser can generate PDF with ER diagram within a few clicks. Tested with PostgreSQL.