# Rails gem to visualized database schema, not just models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a gem that can produce a visualization of a Rails schema, not just the models. In cases where there is a database table in the schema but not corresponding model, I want that table as part of the visualization.

Does such a gem exist?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this one:

https://github.com/preston/railroady

maybe it is what you are looking for

Comment: i have seen it, it seems to only make diagrams for the models and controllers, not also tables

Comment: If you want to go on the database level you shouldn't be searching for gems, you should be searching for database visualization tools. For example if you are using postgresql take a look at this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839282/is-there-data-visualisation-tool-for-postgresql-which-is-capable-of-displaying-i